# Android default browser responsive menu blank

Tags: android, wordpress, responsive

I hope you can help me to solve this problem, I'm using a responsive menu plugin (eDs responsive menu, it uses sidr) on a WordPress site, I tested it on android with default browser, chrome & cm browser.

In chrome displays correctly, but in default browser & cm browser when I open the responsive menu, It's in blank, the same happens with safari on iOS.

I think that it's maybe because some incompatibility with some CSS tags with those browsers but not sure which ones, Can you give me ideas so I can try to find out what is going on.

Here are some image samples:

[Blank menu in default android browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pe5qU.jpg)

[Menu displaying correctly in chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mgKEL.png)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this answer doesn't apply por everyone and is not complete, but the problem is the css tag: **position: fixed** combined with some transitions, it's android default browser and safari problem. I haven't found a fix for this yet.